# How can I create and infinite loop and exit it with a command?

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering if I could make it so a loop can end with typing in a command like end or -1. What I have now is

```
while ( gradeCounter <= 10 ) // loop 10 times
```

I would like to know how to have it loop infinitely till I end it.

Comment: End it asynchronously?

Comment: Use a boolean variable in the conditional statement and set it to false when you want to break out of the loop.

Comment: Make the condition to be false and it will break. If you want it to be a console input you can research on `Scanner` usage and compare the String/input to break the condition.

Comment: Hi, I am like very new to java and I am not sure how to use boolean

Comment: @Tom set it to false *

Comment: @porfiriopartida that depends on the condition :) You're right. Comment fixed.

Comment: @Cube This is exactly the same: `boolean condition = true; while ( condition ) { condition = gradeCounter <= 10; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a while loop and a condition to break it

```
while(true){
      String inputString = //Get user input here       

      if(inputString.equals("Your Termination Text"))
           break;

    }
```

If you want to know how to get console input here is one method
[Java: How to get input from System.console()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/how-to-get-input-from-console-class-in-java)

### Edit per comments below

```
double grades = 0;
int entries = 0;
while(true){
      String inputString = //Get user input here       
 
      if(inputString.equals("Your Termination Text"))
           break;
      else{
        grades += Double.parseDouble(inputString);
        entries++;
      }
 }
 double averageGrade = grades / entries;
```

Please keep in mind that this does not account for text that is not a number and also not your termination text. From the question it sounds like a low level CIS class and I don't think this will be an issue. If it is however you need to learn how to do try catch and some more input validation.

Comment: It's worth mention that the same thing can be done with all of the loops.  Put the above loop body into `for(;;){//loop body from above}` or `do{//loop body from above}while(true);`  Just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: If I have average = total / 10 How do I do average for infinite loop?

Comment: If you need to average, the `for` loop is actually pretty good method.  `for(int i=0;;i++){//find sum, divide by i}`

Comment: You can also use a less clean but just as effective counter declared outside of your loop then just increment it each iteration with counter++

Comment: @AMR i have, in the end to take the average of all data entered. How do I do that if I changed it from set 10 to infinite?

Comment: @Cube I hate to state the obvious but if your loop is infinite it never ends. How do you get the average of something that never ends?

Comment: @AMR When I do use a command like end can I take the average of where it ended?

Comment: @Cube Also please tell me what you are attempting to average?

Comment: @AMR Yea, I have to make a Gradebook data entry thing for homework and in the end it should take average of all the data entered. So If I enter 3 in the end it should give me the average of the 3 if I enter 500 then the average of 500. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Cube that should be your solution above

Comment: @SamYonnou That concept is probably a bit to advanced for someone who would even post this original question...

Comment: @AMR Thank you so much for your help. If it doesn't work can I reply back?

Comment: @Cube I have given you the tools and the resources to do this project. There is a time when you need to do some research yourself. This is a pretty basic CIS problem. If you want to succeed in future classes you need to learn to get friendly with Java Documentation. Good luck bud

Comment: @AMR Thanks, sorry I just wasn't sure how to average an infninite loop

Comment: @Cube if this answers your question please make sure to select the check mark so future people know which answer works

Answer (score 1):

`While(true) {}` creates an infinite loop. A `break` command inside the loop breaks out of it. You'll have to detect whatever sort of event will occur inside the loop to determine if you should break.

I don't know what you're doing on a larger scale, but it could be a better idea to use Threads which don't loop infinitely and suck up processing power.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just make sure, there is a different thread that can handle some kind of input...

```
public class MyBreakableInfiniteLoop

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        new Thread(r).start();

        System.out.println("Press Enter to stop thread");
        new Scanner(System.in).readLine();
        r.stop = true;

    }

    public static class MyRunnable extends Runnable {
       public volatile boolean stop = false;
       public void run() { 
           while(!stop) { 
              //do nothing, preferably in a meaningful way 
           } 
       }
    }


}
```

(aLso, I didn't take into count `kill -9` as "input that breaks the infinite loop"...)