# Getting an input from the user console - Java code

Tags: java, c++, console-application, user-input

What is a Java equivalent for this C++ code snippet:

```
string str ;
while(cin>>str){
   //code
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Comment: can u explain what code mean in while loop

Comment: @Youngistan is plain c++ to read every line from user input and store it into a string.

Comment: Check out this [Java program to get input from user](http://www.msccomputerscience.com/2013/01/write-java-program-to-get-input-from.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
String str ; 
while((str = System.in.readLine()) != null){
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: This is just part of the code. Where's the `while` loop?

Comment: you don't need while loop. you can do your action with this. to finish taking input you can set a flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = true;
while(flag)
{
   String str = scanner.nextLine();

   // Add any condition to set flag = false to exit from while loop
}
```

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza its equivalent to c++ pasted code ??

Comment: forget about equivalent. use it to see you get your desired output

Comment: i dnt knw much abt that operator in c++.What luiggi explain me i rght it @LynAs

Comment: Kinda. Another way can be `String str = null; while ((str = scanner.nextLine() != null) { ... }`.

Comment: yes,to exist the loop we need to write break inside it

Answer (score -1):

you can do it either with a GUI style .

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
String Input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Title","Message");
```