# How do I prompt the user to give the name for the writing and reading serialized file?

Tags: java, serialization

I am making an attempt to prompt the user to create the name for the writing and reading serialized file. E.g. could I do the following:

```
System.out.print("What would you like to name your file?");
String fileName = scanner.nextLine;

try{
 ObjectOutput ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)) // Would this create a file with the name inputted by the user? If so what would be the extension for the file?

 ostream.writeObject(//whatever I want to put in here)

 //close

//catch

try{

 ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName))

//catch
```

Comment: please put your code in blocks so it's readable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unclear questions that don't have a running code example get less attention here. Consider posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) including what you're trying to write to file etc.

Comment: Did you mean name the file before serialize it and then again de-serialize with the same name???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prompt the user for something from the terminal, the easiest way is probably to use `java.io.Console`, in particular one of its `readLine()` methods:

```
import java.io.Console;

...

Console console = System.console();
if (console == null) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("No console to read input from!");
}

String fileName = console.readLine("What would you like to name your file? ");
// Whatever the user inputed is now in fileName
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html.