# Command-line arguments using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, command-line-arguments, netbeans-8

Right click on the project (console/desktop applications that use the `main()` method as an entry point), select the *properties* option from the sub-menu, select the *Run* node, a dialog looking like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGUA8.png) will appear.

[image]

Command line arguments can be set in the *Arguments* box as a space separated list of values. These values are received by the only argument of the `main()` method as an array of Strings.

So, the following program iterates through these values and displays numbers from 1 through 5.

```
public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

These values in this case, can only statically be set and cannot be changed dynamically.

Can these values be fed dynamically to the program (probably through an IO device like the console) so that a user can supply values dynamically as we can do directly through a command-line without using an IDE?

My current environment is :

- NetBeans 8.0.1
- JDK 8u25

Comment: you can probably just set up an IO method for the user and then take these as arguments as well

Comment: maybe this can help you [Java: How to get input from System.console()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console)