# Solving the no console error

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regex,when I compile this code which is from Java Official documentation, I am getting `No Console` error in this code,The [source is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html), I am compiling this code in Eclipse, version Kepler.

The culprit is  `Console console = System.console();`but I do not know why the error is caused.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        while (true) {

            Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));

            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(console.readLine("Enter input string to search: "));

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                console.format("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),
                    matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
                console.format("No match found.%n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Hope this could help you.

Comment: It lloks like a bug in eclipse. [See here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I do not know why the error is caused

Presumably because you're not running it in a console. When you run a Java app in Eclipse, `System.console()` returns null, because it's not a "normal" console. (Personally I think it would be better if Eclipse's console view could be used as the console for this purpose, but apparently that's not the case - at least not yet. See [bug 122429](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429).)

Open a console ("command prompt" in Windows parlance) and run the code there, and you should be fine.

Alternatively, change the code to use standard streams such as `System.in` and `System.out` to read input and write output, instead of using `Console`.

Comment: Thanks a lot coding god for spending your precious time in this question.

Answer (score 0):

This switches all the console stuff to System.in and System.out

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Type in a pattern");
            Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Type in a String to search: ");
            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(input.nextLine());

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.format("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),
                    matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
               System.out.format("No match found.%n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```