# How to ask a user for file name then scan folder for a specific type and if true open the filename if not then throw error

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, input

So I've been looking around to solve my problem but I am only finding part of the solution and I'm trying to modify those solutions to suit my needs but I am not able to do so.

I'm using this class to check for file type..

```
package parser;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
//import java.util.Scanner;

public class FileFilter {
    public File[] finder(String dirName){
        File dir = new File(dirName);
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
        //System.out.flush();
        //String name = scanner.nextLine();

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
                 public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
                     return fileName.endsWith(".xls");
                     }
                 });
    }

}
```

And here's the beginning of my main class that I'm trying to work with (where I ask the user to type in just the file name (without the extension). And this is where I want it to call that FileFilter class and see if the file name typed has the "xls" file extension or not and if not then throw an exception and terminate, if it checks out then continue on...

```
package parser;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ReadExcel {

    static final String ExcelFilePath = "D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Assesment project\\";
    static final String RatesPropFilePath = "D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Assesment project\\rates.properties";
    static final String TotalCostLogFilePath = "D:\\eclipse\\workspace\\Assesment project\\Total_Cost_Log.txt";
    static final int SheetNum = 0;
    static final int CellLookUp = 2;
    static final String AvoidText = "CC";
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReadExcel.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Find all Excel files in folder
        /*FileFilter fileSearch = new FileFilter();
        System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
        System.out.flush();
        String name = fileSearch.*/ // I'm stuck here, and I cannot find a way to fix it.. :S

        // Create an object of File class that points to the Excel file
        File excel = new File(ExcelFilePath);
```

EDIT: To clear the confusion, what I'm trying to do is: I'm trying to make the user to input the file name only (minus the extension). Then when the user enters the file name it then uses the FileFilter class to check if the file name (entered by the user) has the extension defined by the FileFilter (which is xls).. If so, then continue the program (using that file).. If not then throw an error and then terminate. I hope this makes it clearer.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem too hard, let's see (comments inside!)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a FileFilter 
    FileFilter ff = new FileFilter();
    // use finder method to get array of Files
    File[] files = ff.finder(yourFolder);
    // if files is empty
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        // throw or print the error
    } else {
        // iterate over all found files:
        for (File f : files) {
            // f is pointing to excel file
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
According your comment:

> the problem is asking the user for file name then by using the FileFilter class and if it has the extension defined by that class then continue.. if not then throw exception and break.

Well... to ask for file extension, you must do more modifications:

First modify `FileFilter` to accept it:

```
public File[] finder(String dirName, String filename){
    File dir = new File(dirName);

    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            // check for exact filename:
            return name.equals(filename + ".xls");
            // use both parameters to check various files with filename pattern
            return name.endsWith(".xls") && name.startsWith(filename);

        }
    });
}
```

Second use a `Scanner` to get the extension and use it in the `FileFilter` call:

```
System.out.println("Enter file extension: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String extension = scanner.nextLine();
```

Finally, in your `Main` method, make the call with this extension and folder:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a FileFilter 
    FileFilter ff = new FileFilter();
    // ask for extension
    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename= scanner.nextLine();
    // use finder method to get array of Files
    File[] files = ff.finder(yourFolder, filename);
    // if files is empty
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
          // throw the error
    } else {
        // iterate over all found files:
        for (File f : files) {
            // f is pointing to excel file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fadi check my edit... I misunderstood you... hope my update clarifies

Comment: I'm really sorry, I think I'm confusing everyone! Okay so what I'm trying to do is.. the input that i want from the user is the file name only (minus the extension). Then when the person enters the file name it then uses the FileFilter class to check if the file name (entered by the user) has the extension defined by the FileFilter (which is xls).. If so, then continue the program.. If not then throw an error and then terminate. I hope this makes it clearer.. :S

I'll add this to OP..

Comment: @Fadi that's what my edit does... check comments and explanations and you will be able to achieve what you need...

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, then you're asking the user for the extension of the file.. I'm not trying to do that.. I want to ask the user for the file name.. So a user would input something like "MyWorkbook" and then the program checks if "MyWorkbook" has the extension xls (which is already defined in the FileFilter class). If it does end with xls (boolean = true) then use the file.. If not (boolean = false) then throw an error msg and stop the whole program.

Comment: @Fadi ok, check my edit... i put 2 returns in FileFilter to check for `filename.xls`the EXACT filename andto find `MyWork.xsl` **AND** `MyWork2.xls` also, just use the one you prefer...

Comment: Thank you so much Jordi for your time!

Answer (score 1):

What are you stuck on?

**Getting the file name from the user (at the console)**

This is a question of it's own but luckily it's been answered many times on StackOverflow (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console)) and other places, using other methods (such as [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/2003-how-to-read-input-from-console.html)).  Personally I prefer the second one...

```
System.out.println("What is the name of the file: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
fileNameInQuestion = in.nextLine();
```

This is already present in your code but is commented out in `FileFinder`

**Verifying the file exists**

Create an instance of your "Filter", have it search for the given file name using the method you have already then throw an exception if it's not found.

```
//Create instance of your "Filter"
FileFilter fileSearch = new FileFilter();

/**
 * Get the name of and search for the filename in question
 * in the 'directoryToSearch'
 */
File[] file = fileSearch.finder(directoryToSearch);

//If no file is found then throw an Exception
if (file == null || file.length == 0)
{
  throw new Exception();
}
//...continue on...
```

Note that `file` (see [File.listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles())) can be `null` here if the argument `directoryToSearch` is not a directory or can have a `length` of `0` if no files are matching.  Either of these mean there is a problem finding the file so I throw an exception if one or (`||`) the other is true.

**Note about exceptions**

This isn't generally considered proper use of exceptions though.  Mainly because they are supposed to represent exceptional circumstances.  In this case it's more likely you would want to have some validation and feedback of the filename rather than an exception on invalid input, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception).
For this small case though it's not really a big deal, just something to be aware of.

Comment: The problem is, I want to ask the user for a file name, then check if that file has the extension defined by that FileFilter class, if so.. continue.. if not throw an exception and terminate..

Comment: Which is what this code does. What is it that you think it doesn't do?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.. I'm still new to Java and I've never actually done any kind of input from user. So I didn't see in the code anything about input.. but I guess it's the `fileSearch.finder` part that takes care of the input from user?

Comment: Oh, it's the input you are confused with, the problem seems to be with the file check in the description.  Console input from Java is a whole other matter.
I'll add something about that to the question...

Comment: Yeah sorry I think I'm confusing everyone.. I've edited the OP to hopefully make it less confusing..

Comment: I've clarified my answer a fair bit too