# java.lang.NullPointerException - System.console()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.lang.class

I can't solve the problem two hours. Please help me.

**My code**:

```
   package work.anart;
     import java.io.Console;
     public class Office {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
             Console cons = System.console();
             cons.printf("\n");
                 String nbook = "Notebook";
                 double price = 1.75;
             cons.printf(" 1 %10s worth %.2f euro \n", nbook, price);
             cons.printf(" 1 %10s worth %.2f euro \n", nbook, price);
         }
     }
```

**Run**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at work.anart.Office.main(Office.java:8)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: If you've spent 2 hours on it you can surely tell us more about it than pasting the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to get input from System.console()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is working well for me without any errors.I think you are using version less then java 1.7,please use 1.7 or 1.8 because `java.io.Console` was introduced in java 1.7,I feel you should upgrade and check a simple code on your console/terminal.

Comment: I wrote this code. 
`import java.io.Console;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch console");
            return;
        }
        String line = console.readLine();
        console.printf("I saw this line: %s", line);
    }
}`
He said me : `Unable to fetch console`

Comment: I have Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)

Comment: Artem i think you are using eclipse tool or may be another tool to run this program , because eclipse runs your program as a background process and not as a top-level process with  System console or depend on diffrent diffrent IDE  handling of console io. You can use Scanner class like                                                                                             import java.util.Scanner; 
String data;

Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
data= scanInput.nextLine();

scanInput.close();            
System.out.println(data);

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual  >machine, if any.
>
> Returns: The system console, if any, otherwise null.

I guess you don´t have any Console associated with your JVM.

But you could use the System PrintStream like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String nbook = "Notebook";
    double price = 1.75;
    System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, " 1 %10s worth %.2f euro \n", nbook, price);
}
```

Comment: This code is working but Me need use System.console(). In the book, the task on this topic

Comment: I wrote this code. `import java.io.Console; public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { Console console = System.console(); if (console == null) { System.out.println("Unable to fetch console"); return; } String line = console.readLine(); console.printf("I saw this line: %s", line); } }` He said me : `Unable to fetch console `

Comment: I have Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)