# So i just started learning java in treehouse.com ive done the basics but when i try everything ive learnt there on the intellij idea ide nothing works

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, console-application

So I just started learning java in treehouse.com I've done the basics but when i try everything I've learnt there on the intellij idea ide nothing works.

I've already searched the internet trying to find a solution and I still cant find it, yea I've tried system.out but I've seen other people do it with just typing console too and if I try system.out on readline it doesn't work I'm literally confused.

I'm used to using the

```
console.println("Hello world!");
```

and

```
String name=console.readln("whats yo name: ");
```

and stuff like that on the treehouse workspace but everytime i try to do it on intellij idea it keeps getting an error.

it looks like this

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    console.println("dada");



   }
}
```

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i studied the java basics on treehouse not javascript

Comment: "_intellij idea it keeps getting an error._" What specific error do you get ?

Comment: What would be the console variable? I am also confused with your question posed like that.
Were you trying to use something like System.out.println("String here"); ?

Comment: @JonasCz it wont compile

Comment: @ReuelRamosRibeiro it wont compile if i just try to print by using console.println("blablabla");

Comment: Yes, but it tells you what the reason is that it can't compile, that's what I mean. What is the compiler error you're getting ?

Comment: @JonasCz Error:(9, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable console
  location: class com.company.Main

Comment: Treehouse should spend more time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AhmadIzzudinAlifyandra But console just by itself is something that does not exist in Java world. You must use the System.out.println() method do print something to the console. At treehouse, they probably have this method available at your code scope just because of simplicity.

Comment: @AhmadIzzudinAlifyandra **Never** put more information into comments. Always update your question. And please spend some time on the stack overflow help center in order to understand what makes a good question.

Comment: @AhmadIzzudinAlifyandra have you started by using the chapter specific workspace in treehouse. I have done several courses in treehouse and if you follow along pretty much every line of code works. Clearly you havent done everything that the chapter says. Try the workspace also you can check the course on setting up IntelliJ, as you could be missing the SDK for all you know.

Comment: @ReuelRamosRibeiro oh, can you tell me how do i readline then because it doesnt work if i console.readline nor if i system.out.readline. Can you give me a link to the references thanks

Comment: @AhmadIzzudinAlifyandra have you even instatiated this console object? `Console console = new Console()`

Comment: @Clockwork theres a course for intellij idea?!

Comment: @Clockwork yes ive tried that doesnt work

Comment: @AhmadIzzudinAlifyandra yes, the name is Setting up your development environment. However I would recommend using the Workspace for Java Basics as you'd understand better what goes on under the hood.

Comment: Reading your updated code, yes, it won't work, since you don't instantiate the console object. And: `Console` may not work in an IDE: [Java: How to get input from System.console()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4644415) You could use Scanner instead for getting input: [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11871520)

Comment: Yes indeed Console will not work on any IDE, but the code will work on your workspace.

Comment: @Clockwork so i should finish the treehouse java track first your saying before i can fiddle around in an actual ide?

Comment: Well you can always use an IDE, but that would provide you a whole bunch of support which you'd need during production. Doing in the workspace without code help and following the course exactly will help learning and understanding what you're doing a lot better.

Comment: @Clockwork oh well thanks i thought i could instantly use an ide by just learning the basics on treehouse just like i did with c#

Comment: thanks everyone for da help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console console = new Console()
```

This code won't work on IntelliJ.

To take input in an IDE use the following code.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
String in = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(in);
```

You can also use the older way,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
String in = br.readLine();
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can use readline, but not on the console object.