# Finding Position of a word in a string

Tags: java, string, indexing

I’m trying to develop a program that analyses sentence with several words in a string.

When a word in the sentence is inputted the program should identify all the positions that this inputted word occurs in the string. So I if I had the string:

> ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU BUT WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY

And I inputted the word "country" it should output:

> The word Country is in the positions: 5, 17

I’m not really sure where I should start after creating the string

Comment: You can start by reading the [JavaDoc of the `String` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see what it can do for you.

Comment: This is a very simple homework with numerous ways to do it. Read up `String.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the JavaDoc provided in the comment.

Basically when you have `String` you can perform `split` operation by calling `split(" ")` method. This will split whole string into an array `String[]`

Then you can just iterate through the array and print word's position.

Remember: Operations on string can be performed in various ways

Working example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String wholeString = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU BUT WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";
    String[] justWords = wholeString.split(" ");
    String searchString = "COUNTRY";

    for (int i = 0; i < justWords.length; i++) {
        if (justWords[i].equals(searchString)) {
            System.out.println("The word " + searchString + " is in the position: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I am counting since 0 so the position for word COUNTRY will be in 4 and 16 instead of 5 and 17, but you should be able to adjust it to your requirements

Output:

`The word COUNTRY is in the position: 4`

`The word COUNTRY is in the position: 16`

[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Additional Example where String you search for is an user input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter word you are looking for");
    String searchString = br.readLine();

    String wholeString = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU BUT WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY";
    String[] justWords = wholeString.split(" ");


    for (int i = 0; i < justWords.length; i++) {
        if (justWords[i].equals(searchString)) {
            System.out.println("The word " + searchString + " is in the possition: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to check for a user inputted word?

Comment: Sure, read the input from console and put it into String variable to store it, then iterate through and print it back to user :)

How to read from console: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Comment: I edited my answer. Please accept it if it fits your needs :)

Comment: Cheers, this has helped me out

Comment: How do you make it so it inst case sensitive?

Comment: Instead of `equals` you can use `equalsIgnoreCase`