# Prompting user to press any key on the command line during mvn test

Tags: java, maven

I am running unit tests using maven. At one point I need to pause execution in order for the tester to do something. Once they have done it, they need to press a key. I have the following code in my unit test.

```
try {
    while (true) {

        System.out.print("Enter something : ");
        inputResult = System.console().readLine();

    }               
} catch (Exception exc) {
    // exception handling code to 
    // print out message and stack trace        
}
```

When this code is run, an exception is caught which has a stack trace leading to the line:

```
inputResult = System.console().readLine();
```

Why would this be happening? And how might I solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Comment: *"I am running unit tests using maven. At one point I need to pause execution in order for the tester to do something."* this is **not** a *unittest* , exclude that test from automatic execution.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up *UnitTest* with *Tests executed by the JUnit framework.*

By definition a *UnitTest* is some additional code, that verifies the behavior of the production code *automatically*, which in particular means *without user interaction*.

You have three choices (in order of effort needed):

1. exclude this test(s) from beeing executed during maven build.
   You can do so by configuring the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)
2. automate that user interaction too.
3. improve your unittest.
   There is a chance that your test fails the characteristics of a *UnitTest* by not separating the tested unit.

   If you consequently apply the *separation of concerns* principle the user interaction is done in a different unit (class/module) which you should be replaced by a mock during runtime of unittests. These mocks are best created with support of a mocking framework like Mockito, JMock or alike.

I for myself would suggest #3.