# system.console.readline() throws null pointer exception

Tags: java

i am using the following simple code to read a line of string from console but get nullpointerexception, can you folks help:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class readline_String {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //String str=System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter an input string:");
        Console c=System.console();
        String str=c.readLine();
        System.out.println("The input string is:");
        System.out.println(str);

    }

}
```

Comment: From the doc of `System.console()` : "Returns : The system console, if any, otherwise _null_."

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644415/java-how-to-get-input-from-system-console

Comment: Follow Java Naming Conventions: class names should start with uppercase. And don't use underscores, except for constants.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with:

```
    System.out.println("Enter an input string:");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The input string is:");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks  so much this works. Not sure why it doesn't work with system.console.readline()

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying in a IDE(ex: NetBeans) it might show NullPointerException

It shows proper output in a cmd:
code:

```
public class InputConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter something:");
String input = System.console().readLine();
        System.out.println("input: "+input);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Alternatively you can use Scanner or BufferedReader